# How can i edit my laptop screen display edges?

Tags: display, display-settings

My kid has broken my laptop screen. Now (approx 1 inch top to bottom) on the left side of the display i can't see anything. I want to move display to the right. It will be a much help if i can control edges of my screen. I am using ubuntu 20.04.1, Linux hp 5.4.0-48-generic .[image: broken laptop screen]

Comment: This is the most relatable problem I have ever seen!

Comment: There are xorg.conf tweaks that specify the horizontal and vertical offsets of the virtual screen relative to the physical screen dimensions, usually used to arrange a multiple monitors desktop configurations. You may try to dig in this direction.

Comment: I am not an expert in using linux. may be with more knowledge i can do something.